# phpstorm как тестировать локально

Tags: phpstorm

Приветствую. Есть проект в phpstorm, связанный с сервером и github. При коммите измененные файлы заливаются на сервер, при пуше на гитхаб. 
Но хочется тестировать какие-то вещи локально, перед коммитом. Что-бы открывался файл с проекта на локалхосте, как лучше всего это настроить?

Comment: что мешает поднять сервер локально?

Comment: @Nofate Да в целом ничего, просто уверен есть элегантное решение построенное на IDE

Comment: Думаю, это вам поможет - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html

Comment: @Nofate тянет на ответ )

Answer (score -4):

Можно использовать "Джентельменский набор" DENWER, или тот-же OpenServer.

Есть нюанс - оба проекта для Окон... Пингвины не поддерживаются.

Но есть и плюс: оба проекта могут быть как установлены в систему, так и на сменный накопитель (на USB-Flash например) :)

Суть простая: заливать файлы на виртуальные сервера и уже оттуда их тестировать. Кили усё устраивает - делать коммит/PUSH.

Ссыль на Денвер: http://www.denwer.ru/

И на OpenServer: https://ospanel.io/

Comment: Прости господи, но проект DENWER мёртв уже который год. Забудьте про него, всё, хватит, рест-ин-пис. Рекомендуйте OSPanel (бывший OpenServer), рекомендуйте что угодно, но не эту морально устаревшую поделку. PHP5.3 в денвере до сих пор!! Три года не могут выпустить свежую версию PHP в комплекте. В OSPanel есть 5.4, 5.6, 7.0, можно переключаться на любую нужную... я не понимаю, как можно такие советы давать в 2017 году.

Comment: Зачем такую злобу кидать? Не на все проекты требуется что-то выше 5.3. Проект рабочий, то, что он морально устарел не делает его нерабочим, или совсем никому не нужным. Более того, на многих предприятиях до сих пор стоят Окна 2к и ХРюши, а на серверах покоятся Апачи времён Полиолита... А в военкомах/ГСП до сих пор "Зарница" от 1986 г. и данные таскают на дискетках о 3.5 дюймах росту :)    К тому-же я дал рекомендацию, а не настойчиво посоветовал, дал ссылки на главные страницы, чтобы перед скачкой ознакомиться с начинкой и возможностями :)

Comment: ИТ -- быстро развивающаяся отрасль и именно в ней важно не отставать во времени. Учить надо современное и актуальное. Насчёт трёх лет в посте выше я видимо ошибся: на хабре уже в 2012 году (пять лет назад, Карл!) писали что Denwer остановился на PHP5.3 и не движется дальше. Лично я бы предложил OpenServer в котором есть PHP в интервале от 5.2 до 7.1, чем рекомендовать Denwer в котором есть только 5.3 с мотивом "ты будешь успешным сотрудником в окружном военкомате". Злобы нет, минус на ответе не мой -- а резкость в данном случае осознанная, чтобы новички не слушали плохие советы.

Comment: Не воспринимайте минусы как злобу в ваш адрес. К вашей личности они вообще никак не относятся. Видимо, люди категорически осуждают рекомендацию денвера.

Comment: А по рейтингу в -4 можно подумать, что и OpenServer и вообще идея с виртуальным сервером никуда не годятся :(